# BigQuery: question on adding time as a dimension

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to add 'time' or 'date' as a dimension to my Google Analytics query in Big Query...how would I add either daily or monthly 'date' to this query? I understand how to filter on dates in the WHERE statement, but I don't understand how I can add a 'DATE' field to the results displayed. see code attached.

several _TableSuffix options that error out

```
SELECT
  hits.page.pagePath, 
  COUNT(*) AS pageviews
FROM
  `xyz.33759344.ga_sessions_*` AS GA,
  UNNEST(GA.hits) AS hits
WHERE
  hits.type = 'PAGE'
  AND
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20190201' AND '20190331'
AND
hits.page.pagePath LIKE '%step/checkout'
GROUP BY
  hits.page.pagePath
ORDER BY
  pageviews DESC
```

I want to add daily and (as a seperate query) monthly counts to the code.

Answer (score 1):

For showing tally by date, you can simply GROUP BY column date. See below example using public GA sample data.
(Also check [BigQuery Datetime Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions) for how to extract month from date)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT  hits.page.pagePath, 
  COUNT(*) AS pageviews, date
FROM
   `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*` AS GA,
  UNNEST(GA.hits) AS hits
WHERE
  hits.type = 'PAGE'
  AND
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170701' AND '20170801'
AND
hits.page.pagePath LIKE '%/google+redesign/electronics'
GROUP BY
  hits.page.pagePath, date
ORDER BY
  pageviews DESC
```

Results look like:
[image]